# Use a variable to insert into a SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to define an ID with a variable from a spreadsheet, and then use that to open that spreadsheet in the code. See lines 4 and 5 below. For some reason that won't work - I can't pull the ID from the spreadsheet (getValue and then insert it into the SpreadsheetApp.openById line of code).

I know the code works, because if I define the ID in the code itself, it will work. But for some reason I can't pull it from the Spreadsheet.

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Brand1 = sss.getSheetByName('Brand 1');
var Brand1Data = Brand1.getRange('a5:z').getValue();
var key1 = Brand1.getRange('a3').getValues();
var Brand1Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key1);
var BrandDatabase = Brand1Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Database');
BrandDatabase.getRange(BrandDatabase.getLastRow()+1,3,Brand1Data.length, Brand1Data[0].length).setValues(Brand1Data);
```

Comment: How is this called? Manually? Or by a simple trigger? Where is your error log, from Stackdriver? Probably you can resolve this by using the singular `Range#getValue` or by accessing the appropriate element index in the `Array` that is returned by `Range#getValues`. Note the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are unable to get the ID from the sheet is you are using [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) function instead of [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) note the second function doesn't have a 's' at the end. `getValue()` returns the value of a specific cell (or the value of the first cell in a specific range), whereas `getValues()` returns an array which contains all the values in the range. Even if there is just one cell in the range, it will return an array. So the line in the code that gets the spreadsheet ID would be the following:

```
var key1 = Brand1.getRange('a3').getValue();
```

Also, your Brand1Data I presume needs to modified as well:

```
var Brand1Data = Brand1.getRange('a5:z').getValues();
```

To obtain all the values in that range.

Your fixed code will look like this:

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Brand1 = sss.getSheetByName('Brand 1');
var Brand1Data = Brand1.getRange('a5:z').getValues();
var key1 = Brand1.getRange('a3').getValue();
var Brand1Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key1);
var BrandDatabase = Brand1Spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Database');
BrandDatabase.getRange(BrandDatabase.getLastRow()+1,3,Brand1Data.length, Brand1Data[0].length).setValues(Brand1Data)
```

Comment: Thank you! It still isn't working. I get the following error "Bad value (line 7, file "Code")" on the line: "var Brand1Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key1);"

Comment: Ok is this the same error you were getting earlier? Secondly, log the value of key1 see if it matches the key from the sheet!

Comment: Additionally, this code works perfectly on my end. Also, the error basically means the key or ID you are using in your case is not a valid ID. So either the key in the sheet "Brand 1" is incorrect. Or your accessing the wrong sheet or cell where you entered the ID.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks for your help, Jack!